# How can I check if Samsung Smart TV has Internet connection?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I need to know if an Internet connection is available before playing a video.
How can I get it?

```
var url = 'http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4';
//url not found (no Internet)
player.Play(url);
```

Now this code working wrong. Player start play but we have not internet.
How can I be sure that I have a connection to the internet?

```
//pseudo code
if (player.checkInternet){
 player.Play(url);
}else{
 alert('Error');
}
```

Comment: You probably could fetch a really small image and check the length

Answer (score 2):

To check the connectivity of HTTP you can use this following function:
http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00011/deviceapi_network_checkhttp.html

But if for the player, it has some callback functions to handle network error, visit the documentation of player object and see onConnectionFailed, onStreamNotFound, etc
http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/sef_plugin_player.html

Answer (score 1):

I am using this javascript function to check the network on samsung Tv

```
Main.CheckConnection = function () {
    //  if(gKeyValues.IsOnTV){
    //  Main.Print("Production environment-------");
    /* For Production Environment */
    var physicalConnection = 0,
    httpStatus = 0;
    var currentInterface = networkPlugin.GetActiveType();
    // If no active connection.
    if (currentInterface == -1) {   //wired=1,wireless=0,no connection=-1
        return false;
    }
    // Check physical connection of current interface.
    physicalConnection = networkPlugin.CheckPhysicalConnection(currentInterface);
    //  Main.Print("Network Status: " + physicalConnection);

    // If not connected or error.
    if (physicalConnection != 1) {
        //Main.okDialog_Init("Message");
        Main.Print("Network disconnected");
        //  Main.IsNetworkActive = false;
        return false;
    }
    // Check HTTP transport.
    httpStatus = networkPlugin.CheckHTTP(currentInterface);
    // If HTTP is not avaliable.
    if (httpStatus != 1) {
        alert("Network disconnected");
        Main.IsNetworkActive = false;
        return false;
    }
    Main.IsNetworkActive = true;
    return true;
    //  }
};
```

And include this plugin in your HTML page

```
<object id="pluginObjectNetwork" border=0 classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NETWORK" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></object>
```

Please Modify this function according to your requirement this function tackles all the Network and internet related issues in samsun

Comment: what is networkPlugin here? Is it var networkPlugin = document.getElementById('pluginObjectNetwork') ???

Answer (score 0):

You can check the connection status with:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    player.Play(url);
} else {
    alert('Error');
}
```

However, this method may have compatibility issues with some browsers. See: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: userAgent Mozilla/5.0 (SmartHub; SMART-TV; U; Linux/SmartTV; Maple2012) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) SmartTV Safari/534.7